# Cannot expand all the div in a page

Tags: c#, css, google-chrome, html-agility-pack, puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to expand all the divs available inside [this](https://www.diretta.it/) page. In particular the div that shows `mostra partite`, eg:

[image]

Looking to the html structure, we have the class: `event__header--no-my-games` for the collapsed divs, so I did:

```
// page is the browser page
await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(".event"); // wait ajax completion
var divs = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync(".event__header--no-my-games > .event__info");

foreach(var cd in divs)
{
   await cd.ClickAsync();
}
```

the first problem's that the site show 7 divs collapsed, but I get 20 divs on `divs` variable. Also, when I do:

```
string html = await page.GetContentAsync();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

there is no div that has been expanded, what I did wrong?

Comment: Your code is working for me when I launch the browser with `Headless = false`. Did you try taking a screenshot instead of getting the html?

Comment: @hardkoded thanks for the answer, I used `await page.ScreenshotAsync("screen.jpeg");` and I can see that all the divs are collapsed, don't know why on your side it's working

Comment: @hardkoded I tried with `Headless = false` and it works, so I guess is a problem related to the `Headless` mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was working fine:

```
await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(".event"); // wait ajax completion
var divs = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync(".event__header--no-my-games > .event__info");

foreach(var cd in divs)
{
   await cd.ClickAsync();
}
```

the problem was that the browser opened by `Puppeteer` had mobile dimension, in that case the selectors that I was looking for was differents.

I fixed that declaring a `Viewport` size in the following way:

```
Browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
      Headless = true,
      ExecutablePath = "your chrome path",
      DefaultViewport = new ViewPortOptions { Height = 1280, Width = 800}
});
```

this will open the site in desktop mode with correct selectors.

Hope this help someone.